# How are JWT refresh tokens meant to be sent from the client to the backend?

Tags: javascript, jwt, authorization, fetch-api, bearer-token

It is my understanding that, as someone that has recently started using JSON web tokens that, once an **access token** expires, a new one may be generated using a **refresh token**.

I currently have some middleware on my server configured such that, if a JWT verification fails, it uses the **refresh** token to generate a new **access** token and then attempts the verification process again. If this succeeds, it sends a response with the new **access** token attached. If it fails, it sends a 401 error.

For this to work, however, the client must send both the **access** and **refresh** tokens. My fetch requests are currently configured such that they send the **access** token under the `Authorization` header as `Bearer [token]`.

However, when reading the JWT docs, I have come across nothing that refers to the correct manner in which to send the **refresh** token. A brief search returned that it should be sent in the body of a POST request, however, given I am currently sending **both** tokens in **all** fetch requests I make, this would not work for GET requests.

Should I be sending both tokens in all requests? If so how should I send the **refresh** token in a GET request. Given it is stored in the client cookies, I have considered extracting it from there, though I'm curious if there is a better/more generally accepted method.

Comment: Are you implementing custom authorization flow or following OpenID Connect? Where do you store tokens?

Comment: A custom authorization flow (haven't come across OpenID Connect). Currently storing tokens in both cookies and React context.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/. I find it very well written on the subject.